# Почему студенты школы 42 или её франшиз учат программирование с языка C стандарта C99?

Tags: c, c99

Читал про методики обучения студентов программированию, наткнулся на методику обучения, точнее самообучения, студентов франко-американской школы программирования 42 (смотрел школу 21, там тоже самое).

После прохождения нескольких вступительных заданий, студенты попадают в бассейн, своего рода океан, где человек должен научиться плавать самостоятельно, то есть выжить или умереть.

В случае со школой 42, студент за 4 недели или пройдет суровое испытание или будет отчислен.

Во время прохождения бассейна студенты изучают язык программирования C стандарта C99.

Хотел бы услышать ваше мнение, необходимо и целесообразно ли это в, условно, 2022 году?

Грубо говоря, студенту нужно выучить весь C, а это достаточное количество часов, а затем переключиться на другой язык если ему нравится что-то другое.

Я понимаю, что С вездесущ, но всё же...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Это номера каких то малоизвестных московских школ? только в этом случае люди позволяют себе не писать хотя бы страну (то, что язык здесь русский, ещё не значит, что страна - РФ).

Comment: @KoVadim, это про вот это: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(school). Есть несколько пафосных постов на хабре про эту школу: https://habr.com/ru/search/?target_type=posts&order=relevance&q=%5B42%20school%5D

Comment: посмотрел на это. ох ох. Хочешь научится - бери и учись. Литературы - вагон и тележка в интернете. Можно договорится с бабушкой (они обычно любят внуков), что будешь учится, пусть она подгоняет и вовремя кормит, а самому открыть пару курсов курсеры/другой любой онлайн школы) и вперед.  А если бабушке помочь материально перед этим, то процесс пойдет значительно лучше.

Answer (score 2):

По той причине, что если ты знаешь основы - как работает диск, динамическая память, статическая память, стек, процессор. Тебе не сложно выучить любой язык программирования. Как человек знающий asm и си, я сталкиваюсь с минимальным барьером в использовании любого незнакомого мне языка.

Самый близкий из языков к железу остался только Cи, стандарт C99 является де факто самым распространённым, ибо очень мало кто пишет на C11. Обычно на C11 пишутся очень нагруженные асинхронные и thread safe приложения. В остальном C99 очень даже удобен.

Comment: Есть ли какой-то набор тестов, после прохождения которых становится ясно, что студент готов к изучению документации другого языка, например Java?

Comment: Если вы про обучение, то затрудняюсь ответить. Если разговор про профессиональную деятельность, то по большому счёту нет. В каждой компании старпром сам видит подойдёт человек на эту должность или нет. Если к нам на работу устраивается джун и у него аш глаза горят - вот хочет он изучать ту-же Java и логические тесты прошел на ура - то есть смысл пробовать. А если он кислый совсем и тупо ради денег, то таких мы не берём даже на практику. Интерес у человека сразу очевиден, если на тех беседе он интересуется и ищет решение всеми способами, то такой человек заинтересован в самом процессе.

Comment: @Stanislav зачем вообще такие тесты? Как это связано с языком Си? Вполне можно начинать обучение программированию сразу с Java (или любого другого языка) без изучения Си, если вы про это. Си, конечно, знать полезно, но ничто не мешает его изучать не первым языком (и даже не вторым).